# Send Authentication header with fetch or axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, axios

How to send authentication header with `fetch` or `axios` ?

I have tried to do it but it on my client side haven't any header with Authentification value.

Here is my code example.

```js
let myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", token);
myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

let req = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: "no-cors",
        credentials: "same-origin",
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/secret', req)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

And I tried check it on my node.js code.

```js
router.route("/").get(passportJWT, SecretController.secret);
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful problem statement.  Describe the error, or response(s), or issue clearly.  Note that _a problem well defined is half solved already_.

Comment: are you fetching from the same origin? experiment with `credentials: "include",`

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header; it does not belong on a request!!

Comment: `mode: "no-cors"` — Why are you doing that?

Comment: @TiagoCoelho yes, I am.

Comment: `credentials: "same-origin"` + `'http://localhost:5000/secret'` — Why are you using an absolute URL if you are making a same-origin request?

Comment: @Quentin because I am fetchin from locallhost:3000 to locallhost:5000

Comment: @NazariyMural — **Those are different origins!**

Comment: See this master https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898031/how-to-set-cookies-express-react-js/55804086#55804086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two origins to be considered "the same", they must share:

- Scheme (e.g. https)
- Hostname
- Port

You are making a request from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:5000` so are making a cross-origin request.

> ```
> credentials: "same-origin"
> ```

… but you've restricted credentials (like `Authorization`) to *same-origin* requests.

> ```
> mode: "no-cors",
> ```

To send credentials with a cross-origin request, you must have permission via CORS.

You must not set `no-cors`.

You need

```
mode: "cors",
credentials: "include"
```