# How to set cookies express, react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am building a login system using express for `node.js` and `react.js`. In my back-end when a user logs in, it creates a cookie. When I go to Network > Login I can see this:

Set-Cookie:

```
user_id=s%3A1.E%2FWVGXrIgyXaM4crLOoxO%2Fur0tdjeN6ldABcYOgpOPk; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
```

But when I go to Application > Cookies > http://localhost:3000, there is nothing there.  I believe that is because I am not allowing credentials to go through correctly when I do a post request from the client side. How do I go about this? Please, let me know if I can improve my question in any way.

```js
//Login back-end
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    if(validUser(req.body)) {
        User
            .getOneByEmail(req.body.email)
            .then(user => {
                if(user) {
                    bcrypt
                        .compare(req.body.password_digest, user.password_digest)
                        .then((result) => {
                            if(result) {
                                const isSecure = process.env.NODE_ENV != 'development';

                                res.cookie('user_id', user.id, {
                                    httpOnly: true,
                                    secure: isSecure,
                                    signed: true
                                })
                                res.json({
                                    message: 'Logged in'
                                });
                            } else {
                                next(new Error('Invalid Login'))
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    next(new Error('Invalid Login'))
                }
            });
    } else {
        next(new Error('Invalid Login'))
    }
});

//Allow CORS index.js
app.use(
cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
})
);

//Login client side (React.js)
loginUser(e, loginEmail, password) {
e.preventDefault();

let email = loginEmail;
let password_digest = password;
let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password_digest });

fetch("http://localhost:5656/api/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(user => {
    console.log(user);
    });
}
```

Comment: Use react-cookie library, then you can use cookies.get('key' ) and cookies.set('key', 'value')

Comment: Thank you for your comment Sameer. However, I could not make it work. I am using universal cookie like this:

    import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

    const cookies = new Cookies();

    cookies.set('myCat', 'Pacman', { path: '/' });
    console.log(cookies.get('myCat')); // Pacman

When I go to Application > Cookies > http://localhost:3000, I can see this 'myCat' cookie there. But I am not sure how to integrate that with my application. (I am trying to display the code correctly but I can't.)

Comment: All of your configuration seems correct except 1 thing that I'm not sure about. When you're setting the cookie in your login post route, make sure that the `secure` flag is false (only for development). In production, set that to `true`. This is because localhost is HTTP not HTTPS. So make sure your `isSecure` variable is false. That's the only thing that looks like a potential issue to me.

Comment: @HarshitTrehan - FYI and for others benefit too. As per latest MDN docs - `localhost` is an exception for `secure` flag. Link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not forget to adjust cors middleware.

**Your node.js express code**

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

app.use(cors(
  {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  }
));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  )
  next()
})

app.get("/auth", function(req, res){

  res.cookie('token', 'someauthtoken')
  res.json({id: 2});
});

app.listen(3030);
```

**Your front-end code**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


async function loginUser() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      'http://localhost:3030/auth',
      {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )
    return res
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    loginUser();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be secure of set "credentials" in the server and in app.

Try to set on you index.js or app.js server side this:

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  )
  next()
})
```

and in you client site add options like this:

```
let axiosConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
}

export async function loginUser(data) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${URL}:${PORT}/${API}/signin`,
      data,
      axiosConfig
    )
    return res
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

#### Edit

To set "credentials" in server we need this line:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
```

This would let you handle credentials includes in headers.

You also have to tell to `axios` to set credentials in headers with:

```
withCredentials: true
```

Comment: on 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', does the true need to be quoted? i was getting a CORS until i added that line (and everything else mentioned here) and quoted the true. it seems to be working now. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure **cors** in your backend server first.

First, install cors using `npm i cors` then in your express server add this line of code:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: "YOUR FRONTEND SITE URL HERE",
  credentials: true,
}));
```

Then, in your frontend app where you are sending GET/POST requests to your backend, make sure to add in your request

If you've used **fetch**:

```
const res = await fetch('BACKEND SERVER URL', {
   credentials: "include",
   // other objects
});
```

If **axios** is used:

```
const res = await axios.post('BACKEND SERVER URL',  
     { withCredentials: true },
     // other objects,
);
```

This will solve the problem of storing cookies in frontend sent from backend.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set `httpOnly: true`.

This will block the visibility to client side, like reading from javaScript `document.cookie()`.

You can solve this by turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see your cookie in the browser, I think it is because you're setting hhtpOnly to true in the cookie's options.

cookie.httpOnly
Specifies the boolean value for the HttpOnly Set-Cookie attribute. When truthy, the HttpOnly attribute is set, otherwise it is not. By default, the HttpOnly attribute is set.

**Note**: be careful when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not allow client-side JavaScript to see the cookie in document.cookie

```js
   res.cookie('user_id', user.id, {
                                            httpOnly: false, // try this
                                            secure: isSecure,
                                            signed: true
                                        })
```